# Explanation of Simple SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

I have a question on how the less than operator is used in this SQL query that answers the following English statement:

```
Drinkers who frequent at least two bars
```

NOTE: there is a table called frequents with columns of drinker and bar.

Now, I solved this originally by utilizing the `group by` and `having count` operators, but I have stumbled upon this query which also is correct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1.drinker
FROM frequents f1, frequents f2
WHERE f1.drinker = f2.drinker
AND f1.bar < f2.bar
```

I am having a little trouble understanding the mechanics of this query, specifically with the final AND statement.

Comment: I believe that < sign is supposed to be <> which should give somewhat correct results since it still queries not equal.

Comment: @Engin the point of using the `<` instead of `<>` is preventing from getting the pairs in both orders. (a, b) and (b, a). Since there is a DISTINCT, it is slightly moot for final results, but could be improving performance.

Comment: It's not moot. Without it *every* drinker would be returned.

Comment: @Uueerdo hah! never thought of that, maybe because of the distinct. Thank you.

Comment: @aquinas the choice of `<`  vs `<>` is moot, not the use of a general not equal operator.

Answer (score 0):

The table is joined with itself on the same drinker.  Now in order for f1.bar < f2.bar implies f1.bar != f2.bar.  Thus 2 bars (maybe more).

Answer (score 0):

It would have made a bit more sense if the final and said AND `f1.bar <> f2.bar`

So, the idea here is that there is a cartesian join happening: every row of table 1 is joined against every row of table 2. So you can imagine your result set consists of the number of rows in `frequents` times itself. e.g., if you have 10 rows in frequents you'll have 100 rows in your result set: each row joined with every other row. OK. So from that result set, you are now saying, well, I only care about the rows where the frequent id is the same but the *bar* they frequent is different. Obviously, the f1.bar <> f2.bar is necessary because otherwise every row would match with itself. This guarantees that the frequenter has at LEAST two rows that show up. The distinct takes care of removing the additional duplicates. Note: count(*) and group by is a much better approach.